# My eclipse does not have import gradle function?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I need to import a gradle projct into eclipse, but when I do File > Import I  get this ...

[image]

... I don't see any Gradle option. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

I found these instructions here https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/

Installing Gradle Tooling from update site

Alternatively you can install from update sites. The following update sites are available:

http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/gradle/nightly (latest development snapshot)
http://dist.springsource.com/milestone/TOOLS/gradle (latest milestone build)
http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle (latest release)
Pasting the above URLs into a web browser will not work. You need to follow the instructions given below to use an Eclipse update site.

In Eclipse Open Help >> Install New Software
Paste a Gradle update site link into the "Work with" text box.
Click the Add button at the top of the screen.
Ensure that the option "Group Items by Category" is enabled.
Select the top-level node 'Extensions / Gradle Integration'.
Click "Next". This may take a while.
Review the list of software that will be installed. Click "Next" again.
Review and accept licence agreements and Click "Finish".
If you follow this installation procedure in a plain Eclipse, this will install the STS Dashboard.